# Unknown server tag 'asp:ScriptManager' and 'asp:ListView'

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I recently copied over a fully functional website from source gear

It won't build.

Everything seems to be there, but i am getting

**Unknown server tag 'asp:ScriptManager' and 'asp:ListView'**

I am running 3.5 for this project. (yes i have that framework installed on my server too)

What am i missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Be sure that you have in `web.config`

```
 <pages>
    <controls>
      <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </controls>
  </pages>
```

Comment: i do and thats the scary part :|

Comment: :) Why are you saying that?

Comment: @Pinch Indeed is the scary part.

Comment: @Pinch Try to drag n drop from toolbox these controls and then just delete them.

Comment: same issue even when i dragged a new one

Comment: Odd this. Question gets no up voting. However; the answer, not helping OP I might add, has a sum of six up votes, by the time this is written. People are funny.